# EAS build failed because I don't have Android directory

Tags: android, expo, eas

I have react native project, which I used to test it on Expo Go. That is, I dont have `android` or `ios` directories in this project. Do I need to? I want to test my project on my android device, so I run `eas build --profile development --platform android`. This is my `eas.json` file:

```
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 0.60.0"
  },
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal",
      "ios": {
        "simulator": true
      }
    },
    "preview": {
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "production": {}
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {}
  }
}
```

Before, when I tested my app, I tested it on Expo Go, and I just executed `npx expo start -c` and I was able to run the app on my device. Now, I need to create this eas build, which is failing I presume, because I dont have `android` directory. How should I create one in my react native project? Also, I think it is worth mentioning that my `Prebuild` phase passed successfully. That is

```
- Creating native project directories (./ios and ./android) and updating .gitignore
✔ Created native project | gitignore skipped
- Adding Metro bundler config
- Updating your package.json scripts, dependencies, and main file
✔ Updated package.json and added index.js entry point for iOS and Android
- Config syncing
```

was successful, yet, my `Gradle build` step is failing because there is problem with `compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle`

This is the output from my Android internal distribution build:

```
Running 'gradlew :app:assembleDebug' in /home/expo/workingdir/build/android
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5.1-all.zip
10%.
20%.
30%
40%.
50%.
60%.
70%.
80%.
90%.
100%
Welcome to Gradle 7.5.1!
Here are the highlights of this release:
 - Support for Java 18
- Support for building with Groovy 4
- Much more responsive continuous builds
 - Improved diagnostics for dependency resolution
For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/release-notes.html
To honour the JVM settings for this build a single-use Daemon process will be forked. See https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html#sec:disabling_the_daemon.
Daemon will be stopped at the end of the build
> Task :react-native-gradle-plugin:pluginDescriptors
> Task :react-native-gradle-plugin:processResources
> Task :expo-dev-launcher-gradle-plugin:pluginDescriptors
> Task :expo-dev-launcher-gradle-plugin:processResources
> Task :expo-dev-launcher-gradle-plugin:compileKotlin
> Task :expo-dev-launcher-gradle-plugin:compileJava
NO-SOURCE
> Task :expo-dev-launcher-gradle-plugin:classes
> Task :expo-dev-launcher-gradle-plugin:jar
> Task :expo-dev-launcher-gradle-plugin:inspectClassesForKotlinIC
> Task :react-native-gradle-plugin:compileKotlin
> Task :react-native-gradle-plugin:compileJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :react-native-gradle-plugin:classes
> Task :react-native-gradle-plugin:inspectClassesForKotlinIC
> Task :react-native-gradle-plugin:jar
> Configure project :app
 ℹ️  Applying gradle plugin 'expo-dev-launcher-gradle-plugin' (expo-dev-launcher@2.2.1)
> Configure project :expo-application
WARNING:Software Components will not be created automatically for Maven publishing from Android Gradle Plugin 8.0. To opt-in to the future behavior, set the Gradle property android.disableAutomaticComponentCreation=true in the `gradle.properties` file or use the new publishing DSL.
> Configure project :expo-av
WARNING:Software Components will not be created automatically for Maven publishing from Android Gradle Plugin 8.0. To opt-in to the future behavior, set the Gradle property android.disableAutomaticComponentCreation=true in the `gradle.properties` file or use the new publishing DSL.
Checking the license for package NDK (Side by side) 23.1.7779620 in /home/expo/Android/Sdk/licenses
License for package NDK (Side by side) 23.1.7779620 accepted.
Preparing "Install NDK (Side by side) 23.1.7779620 (revision: 23.1.7779620)".
"Install NDK (Side by side) 23.1.7779620 (revision: 23.1.7779620)" ready.
Installing NDK (Side by side) 23.1.7779620 in /home/expo/Android/Sdk/ndk/23.1.7779620
"Install NDK (Side by side) 23.1.7779620 (revision: 23.1.7779620)" complete.
"Install NDK (Side by side) 23.1.7779620 (revision: 23.1.7779620)" finished.
Checking the license for package CMake 3.22.1 in /home/expo/Android/Sdk/licenses
License for package CMake 3.22.1 accepted.
Preparing "Install CMake 3.22.1 (revision: 3.22.1)".
"Install CMake 3.22.1 (revision: 3.22.1)" ready.
Installing CMake 3.22.1 in /home/expo/Android/Sdk/cmake/3.22.1
"Install CMake 3.22.1 (revision: 3.22.1)" complete.
"Install CMake 3.22.1 (revision: 3.22.1)" finished.
> Configure project :expo-blur
WARNING:Software Components will not be created automatically for Maven publishing from Android Gradle Plugin 8.0. To opt-in to the future behavior, set the Gradle property android.disableAutomaticComponentCreation=true in the `gradle.properties` file or use the new publishing DSL.
> Configure project :expo-camera
WARNING:Software Components will not be created automatically for Maven publishing from Android Gradle Plugin 8.0. To opt-in to the future behavior, set the Gradle property android.disableAutomaticComponentCreation=true in the `gradle.properties` file or use the new publishing DSL.
> Configure project :expo-constants
WARNING:Software Components will not be created automatically for Maven publishing from Android Gradle Plugin 8.0. To opt-in to the future behavior, set the Gradle property android.disableAutomaticComponentCreation=true in the `gradle.properties` file or use the new publishing DSL.
> Configure project :expo-crypto
WARNING:Software Components will not be created automatically for Maven publishing from Android Gradle Plugin 8.0. To opt-in to the future behavior, set the Gradle property android.disableAutomaticComponentCreation=true in the `gradle.properties` file or use the new publishing DSL.
> Configure project :expo-dev-client
WARNING:Software Components will not be created automatically for Maven publishing from Android Gradle Plugin 8.0. To opt-in to the future behavior, set the Gradle property android.disableAutomaticComponentCreation=true in the `gradle.properties` file or use the new publishing DSL.
> Configure project :expo-dev-launcher
WARNING:Software Components will not be created automatically for Maven publishing from Android Gradle Plugin 8.0. To opt-in to the future behavior, set the Gradle property android.disableAutomaticComponentCreation=true in the `gradle.properties` file or use the new publishing DSL.
> Configure project :expo-dev-menu
WARNING:Software Components will not be created automatically for Maven publishing from Android Gradle Plugin 8.0. To opt-in to the future behavior, set the Gradle property android.disableAutomaticComponentCreation=true in the `gradle.properties` file or use the new publishing DSL.
> Configure project :expo-dev-menu-interface
WARNING:Software Components will not be created automatically for Maven publishing from Android Gradle Plugin 8.0. To opt-in to the future behavior, set the Gradle property android.disableAutomaticComponentCreation=true in the `gradle.properties` file or use the new publishing DSL.
> Configure project :expo-device
WARNING:Software Components will not be created automatically for Maven publishing from Android Gradle Plugin 8.0. To opt-in to the future behavior, set the Gradle property android.disableAutomaticComponentCreation=true in the `gradle.properties` file or use the new publishing DSL.
> Configure project :expo-file-system
WARNING:Software Components will not be created automatically for Maven publishing from Android Gradle Plugin 8.0. To opt-in to the future behavior, set the Gradle property android.disableAutomaticComponentCreation=true in the `gradle.properties` file or use the new publishing DSL.
> Configure project :expo-font
WARNING:Software Components will not be created automatically for Maven publishing from Android Gradle Plugin 8.0. To opt-in to the future behavior, set the Gradle property android.disableAutomaticComponentCreation=true in the `gradle.properties` file or use the new publishing DSL.
> Configure project :expo-image-loader
WARNING:Software Components will not be created automatically for Maven publishing from Android Gradle Plugin 8.0. To opt-in to the future behavior, set the Gradle property android.disableAutomaticComponentCreation=true in the `gradle.properties` file or use the new publishing DSL.
> Configure project :expo-image-manipulator
WARNING:Software Components will not be created automatically for Maven publishing from Android Gradle Plugin 8.0. To opt-in to the future behavior, set the Gradle property android.disableAutomaticComponentCreation=true in the `gradle.properties` file or use the new publishing DSL.
> Configure project :expo-image-picker
WARNING:Software Components will not be created automatically for Maven publishing from Android Gradle Plugin 8.0. To opt-in to the future behavior, set the Gradle property android.disableAutomaticComponentCreation=true in the `gradle.properties` file or use the new publishing DSL.
> Configure project :expo-json-utils
WARNING:Software Components will not be created automatically for Maven publishing from Android Gradle Plugin 8.0. To opt-in to the future behavior, set the Gradle property android.disableAutomaticComponentCreation=true in the `gradle.properties` file or use the new publishing DSL.
> Configure project :expo-keep-awake
WARNING:Software Components will not be created automatically for Maven publishing from Android Gradle Plugin 8.0. To opt-in to the future behavior, set the Gradle property android.disableAutomaticComponentCreation=true in the `gradle.properties` file or use the new publishing DSL.
> Configure project :expo-location
WARNING:Software Components will not be created automatically for Maven publishing from Android Gradle Plugin 8.0. To opt-in to the future behavior, set the Gradle property android.disableAutomaticComponentCreation=true in the `gradle.properties` file or use the new publishing DSL.
> Configure project :expo-manifests
WARNING:Software Components will not be created automatically for Maven publishing from Android Gradle Plugin 8.0. To opt-in to the future behavior, set the Gradle property android.disableAutomaticComponentCreation=true in the `gradle.properties` file or use the new publishing DSL.
> Configure project :expo-media-library
WARNING:Software Components will not be created automatically for Maven publishing from Android Gradle Plugin 8.0. To opt-in to the future behavior, set the Gradle property android.disableAutomaticComponentCreation=true in the `gradle.properties` file or use the new publishing DSL.
> Configure project :expo-modules-core
WARNING:Software Components will not be created automatically for Maven publishing from Android Gradle Plugin 8.0. To opt-in to the future behavior, set the Gradle property android.disableAutomaticComponentCreation=true in the `gradle.properties` file or use the new publishing DSL.
> Configure project :expo-notifications
WARNING:Software Components will not be created automatically for Maven publishing from Android Gradle Plugin 8.0. To opt-in to the future behavior, set the Gradle property android.disableAutomaticComponentCreation=true in the `gradle.properties` file or use the new publishing DSL.
> Configure project :expo-permissions
WARNING:Software Components will not be created automatically for Maven publishing from Android Gradle Plugin 8.0. To opt-in to the future behavior, set the Gradle property android.disableAutomaticComponentCreation=true in the `gradle.properties` file or use the new publishing DSL.
[stderr] 
FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.
[stderr] 
1: Task failed with an exception.
[stderr] 
-----------
[stderr] 
* Where:
[stderr] 
Build file '/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-screen-orientation/android/build.gradle' line: 3
[stderr] 
* What went wrong:
[stderr] 
A problem occurred evaluating project ':expo-screen-orientation'.
[stderr] 
> Plugin with id 'maven' not found.
[stderr] 
* Try:
[stderr] 
>
[stderr] 
Run with
[stderr] 
--stacktrace
[stderr] 
option to get the stack trace.
[stderr] 
>
[stderr] 
Run with
[stderr] 
--info
[stderr] 
or
[stderr] 
--debug
[stderr] 
option to get more log output.
[stderr] 
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
[stderr] 
==============================================================================
[stderr] 
2: Task failed with an exception.
[stderr] 
-----------
[stderr] 
* What went wrong:
[stderr] 
A problem occurred configuring project ':expo'.
[stderr] 
> compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle
[stderr] 
* Try:
[stderr] 
> Run with
[stderr] 
--stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
[stderr] 
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
[stderr] 
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
[stderr] 
==============================================================================
[stderr] 
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
[stderr] 
BUILD FAILED in 2m 43s
10 actionable tasks: 10 executed
Error: Gradle build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run gradlew" phase for more information.

Fail build
```

Can someone advice please?

Answer (score 0):

I want to answer my own question, in case people struggle with the same problems.

Basically, I went through all packages listed inside my `package.json` file. Removed unused ones, and updated some of the rest, not all. Also, run `npx expo-doctor`, and fixed everything that needed to be fixed there. Made sure I don't have `android` dir in my project, and the eas build was successful.